# iwconfig Access Point: Not-Associated

Tags: network-interface, ifconfig

I'm trying to set up my wireless adapter in Debian using iwpriv but in order for me to request an ip with dhclient I need to have the Access Point's SSID configured. My question is how do I get the AP's SSID? If I compared the value of my wlan0 interface to my ra0 interface it looks like a MAC address and I don't see a MAC address on the adapter and I don't know what value to put in there.

```
iwpriv ra0 set NetworkType=Infra
iwpriv ra0 set AuthMode=WPA2PSK
iwpriv ra0 set EncrypType=TKIP
iwpriv ra0 set SSID="MyAP"
iwpriv ra0 set WPAPSK=1234567 <-- not my acutal pswd 
iwpriv ra0 set WirelessMode=14
iwpriv ra0 set SSID="AP's SSID" <-- here is where I'm supposed to enter the ap's ssid
```

After I enter those commands here's what `iwconfig ra0` shows

```
Ralink STA  ESSID:"MyAP"  Nickname:"MT7610U_STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=5.18 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```